# CollapsiblePanelExtender A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am encountering this error whenever the button is clicked to collapse/expand the panel.
Error: CollapsiblePanelExtender A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client.

Can someone tell me what I did wrong and what is causing this?

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
 <ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender 
    TargetControlID="testPanel" 
    ID="CollapsiblePanelExtender1" 
    runat="server"
    ExpandControlid="Button1"
    CollapseControlID="Button1" 
    Collapsed="False" 
    ExpandDirection="Vertical" 
    AutoCollapse="false" 
    AutoExpand="false">

</ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender>

<asp:Panel ID="testPanel" runat="server">
    stuff here
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `validateRequest="false"` in your page directive or web.config file.

[Adding Cross-Site Scripting Protection to ASP.NET](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972967.aspx)

for example if you already have:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="MyForm.aspx.vb"  Inherits="Proj.MyForm"%>
```

then this should become:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="MyForm.aspx.vb" Inherits="Proj.MyForm" ValidateRequest="false"%>
```

Note:

If you are using .NET 4 then you will need to add requestValidationMode="2.0" to the httpRuntime configuration section of the web.config file. For example:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

If you don't already have a httpRuntime section in the web.config file then this goes inside the  section.

Thanks

Comment: thanks it worked, but what exactly does validateRequest="false" do?